# i had Error Exception has occurred: TypeError tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str (Open CV)?

Tags: python

can anyone help me i'm stuck on argparse for objectdetection open cv, first
i use

```py
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

had an error systemExit2 but is fine now when use args['bal..bla'], ['bla..bla'] but the next error TypeError tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
#start from here
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", '-f',"--prototxt", required=True,
help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True, 
help="path to Caffe pre-trained model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.2,
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = ['prototxt'], ['model']


CLASSES = ["background", "aeroplane", "bicycle", "bird", "boat",
    "bottle", "bus", "car", "cat", "chair", "cow", "diningtable",
    "dog", "horse", "motorbike", "person", "pottedplant", "sheep",
    "sofa", "train", "tvmonitor"]
COLORS = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(CLASSES), 3))

#Error on this section
print("[INFO] loading model...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args['prototxt'],['model'])'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You you are making a constant valued tuple for `args`:

```
args = ['prototxt'], ['model']
```

You need to get the value for `args` from your argument parser.

```
args = ap.parse_args()
```

Comment: this will have error Exception has occurred: SystemExit
2

Comment: i use `args = vars(ap.parse_args())` thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

i'm using import

```
 from imutils.video import VideoStream
 from imutils.video import FPS
 import numpy as np
 import argparse
 import imutils
 import time
 import cv2
 import sys
 import os
```

i'm using python 3.6.5
opencv 4.2.0
using visual studio